# Writing expressions as column matrix...B-splines?

Tags: numerical-methods

The question: Evaluate $$\sum_{k=0}^4 c_kx^k$$ for $x=0,1,2,3,4$. Write these five expressions as a matrix product $Mc$, where $M$ is a 5x5 matrix, and $c$ is a column matrix with components $c_0,c_1,....,c_4$.

Would I just plug in the different $x$ values for this? 
We're covering uniform B-splines, but I don't see how this has anything to do with it.

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This problem does not directly involve B-splines, but it teaches you background knowledge you need in order to understand B-splines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $M$ is
\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & x_0^4 \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & x_1^4 \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & x_2^3 & x_2^4 \\
1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & x_3^3 & x_3^4 \\
1 & x_4 & x_4^2 & x_4^3 & x_4^4 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $x_k = k$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4$.